# Proper usage of .ajax jquery method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want the request to delete a record from sql without changing the web page. Unfortunately its not actually deleting the record when I click this button. What is wrong with post_action.php to cause the delete to fail?

post_action.php

```
 <?php
if($_GET['action'] == "deletePost")
        deletePost($_GET['title'])
function deletePost($title){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM blog WHERE Title = '$title';";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
}
?>
```

Ajax Request:

```
$('#deletePost').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"post_action.php",
        data: {action: "deletePost",  postTitle: $(this).siblings("h3.blog").text()},
        success: function(result){
            $('ul.left').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

index.php

```
<?php
            include 'scripts/db_connect.php';
            include 'scripts/functions.php';
            sec_session_start();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo'<div class="blog"><h3 class="blog">' . $row['Title'] . 
                "</h3><h3>" . $row['Date'] . "</h3><h3>" . $row['Tag'] . 
                "</h3><hr>";
                echo'<p class="blog">' . $row['Body'] . '</p><form name="postForm" 
                method="post" action="process_post.php">
                <input type="radio" name="postAction" 
                value="editPost" class="postButton"  type="button">Edit</input>
                <input type="radio" name="postAction" value="deletePost" 
                class="postButton" type="button">Delete</input>
                <input type="radio" name="postAction" value="commentPost" 
                class="postButton"  type="button">Comment</input>
                </form></div>';
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: I would not send the whole SQL query on the front-end. I would just send the relevant table or WHERE value. Otherwise, you are most likely opening your database up for abuse.

Comment: why you are using post title for removing use Id instead of title

Comment: Because its a dummy example to help me learn guys. This is on my localhost not a website with traffic :)

Comment: success function holds response.. which is after the sql query.. I think you misunderstood the concept.

Comment: You're completely right mr_green. /facepalm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on you, what you will return from the server side as confirmation of your deletion, for example, if you write your `deletePost` function like this (Assumed `$mysqli` is available to your current scope)

```
function deletePost($title){
    // include 'scripts/db_connect.php';
    $sql = "DELETE FROM blog WHERE title = '$title'";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    if( mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

And use it like

```
if( deletePost ($_GET['postTitle'] ) ) {
    echo 'succeed';
}
else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

So, in your `ajax success` fnction you may use something like this

```
success:function($data){
    if($data == 'succeed') alert('Record Deleted');
    else alert('Record Not Deleted');
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Now do you have any idea what might cause it to fail? I have an alert in my success right now and its not alerting, not to mention the record I'm trying to delete is still visible! :(

Comment: Did you see any error messages in your console ? Do you have a valid connection and is `$mysqli` available in the function scope ?

Comment: I tried echoing a bunch of divs at the top of post_action.php and none of them show. I'm not sure if that means its reaching the php file and failing to return the ajax request, or failing to get to the php file altogether. I double checked and both file are in the same folder so I know my directory is correct...

Comment: Did you `include 'scripts/db_connect.php';` at the top of your `post_action.php` ?

Comment: I didn't have them included. I do now though. Still no luck. I'll work on rubber ducking it until I post another question. Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome and also make sure that you can delete a record from your browser using `http://localhost/post_action.php?postTitle=sometitle` and check browser's console too, for errors.

Comment: How do I check browsers console? And also ++++ a million for that url. That will be invaluable as I debug!

Comment: Depends on browser you are using, from chrome, right click, select `inspect element` and then click `console` tab.

Answer (score 1):

Problem ;
you are sending data:

```
    `data: {action: "deletePost",  postTitle: $(this).siblings("h3.blog").text()}`,
```

but you are using

```
$_GET['title'] instead use $_GET['postTitle']
```

Secondly: Success function to be called if the request succeeds. So in it you can do many things here like:

```
1. show a confirmation box sayin deleted successfully.
2. show a div giving confirmation.
3. remove the deleted row(should be done in all options)
```

Comment: Sorry for the amateur-ness. This is my first ajax attempt lol. I was using the API to write that code and I thought I read that the .ajax jquery method data settings fill a $_GET array with the data members which is what I thought I was doing!

Comment: @CodeManiak yes but you are doing it ight. It will give you data in $_GET which is default method. Untill you specify method to be post you will get data in $_GET. The problem was you were using title index instead of postTitle

Comment: Hmm I fixed that and still no dice. Any other insights to share? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

> A Success function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR

```
success: function(result){
     //perform function after succesfull deletion
     //for example : notifying user of record successfully deleted
     alert('DELETED SUCESSFULLY');
}
```

**REFERENCE**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I meant more like what would the success function look like if you were to design a delete script for a mySQL record. such as... confirmation output that the delete worked or something

Comment: So I put that alert in my success: and it never fires off which means my ajax request is failing. Any ideas why?